# Delete pointer but does not NULL

Tags: c++

For example, I have a class `Inventory`, and a class `Item`.

```
class CInventory:
   CItem* m_pItem; // Member Variable

CInventory(CItem* pItem)
   :m_pItem(pItem)
{}

// Function
if(NULL == m_pItem)
   return;
```

In proceed, Item is disappeared, so I delete the item.

```
template<class T>
static inline void safe_delete(T& rData)
{
if(rData)
    {
    delete rData;
    rData = NULL;
    }
 }
```

However, Function in CInventory `if(NULL == pItem)` doesn't work.
I found out that they have all the same pointer.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The code you posted seems incomplete. Pleas update with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you expecting that function to modify every pointer to a particular `CItem`? It only modifies the pointer you pass to it. (And `delete`ing a null pointer is safe; you can remove the check.)

Comment: Consider changing the name of that function from `safe_delete` to `sort_of_safe_delete`. `CInventory* p1 = new CInventory; CInventory* p2 = p1; safe_delete(p1);` `p2` now points to freed memory. The solution to dangling pointers is in **design**, not low level hacks.

Comment: don't use new and delete at all! Consider using smartpointers. Also note that NULL is deprectated, use nullptr instead.

Comment: @The Techel: `NULL` is deprecated?

Comment: @AnT Yes, because NULL is defined as just `0` in C++, which creates problems when overloading functions for `int` and pointers

Comment: @stackptr: We all know the "because" (and no, I woudn't refer to it as "problems"). But was `NULL` offically given *deprecated* status in C++17? I don't see it in the draft.

Comment: @The Techel: That is false. `NULL` is **not** deprecated in C++. Please, don't make up things involving formal terminology.

Comment: I was using the term *deprecated* in it's usual context. I did not mean that NULL is deprecated in terms of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your `safe_delete` seems to do the job of deleting the allocated memory for a given pointer (and sets it to null), but this doesn't invalidate any OTHER pointers that points to the same memory (which is now garbage anyway).

```
int main()
    {
    int* pA = new int(); // let's say pA = 0x4420ffbe
    int* pB = pA; // pB = pA = 0x4420ffbe

    // equivalent to safe_delete
    delete pA;
    pA = nullptr; // pA = 0x00000000

    // pB still points to 0x4420ffbe


    return 0;
    }
```

What you would want is along the lines of a `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or  `weak_ptr`